# MS Access Overflow - Dealing with division by 0

Tags: sql, debugging, ms-access, overflow

I have the following expression in an MS Access Query, where some of these values can be null and despite the cast to a Decimal and the Not Zero (NZ) function, I still get an overflow error.

```
Sum(Cdec(Nz([TotalPrice]/([tbl_ArticlesPerOrder]![Amount]*[Total])*[tbl_ArtikelRemoveFromSawList]![Amount]),0))
```

EDIT: Removing the TotalPrice division removes the overflow.  So I suspect a division by 0. Any way to deal with that?

Comment: You know, you really only needed to post this question the one time. You've gotten much better answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to see if you can build an `IFf` statement **within** your sum to handle the division by zero.

e.g.

```
IIf([tbl_ArticlesPerOrder]![Amount]*[Total])=0,0,[TotalPrice]/([tbl_ArticlesPerOrder]![Amount]*[Total])
```

[MS LINK: Avoiding divide by zero errors in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA010550731033.aspx)

(Edited based on Kev's comments)

Comment: I did exactly that and then got the overflow error again. 

Now I'm doing this calculation through VBA and I get a type mismatch error.  Any ideas?

Comment: The above function was checkin the wrong part of the fraction, you need to check if ([tbl_ArticlesPerOrder]![Amount]*[Total]) is 0 not[TotalPrice]. Does it still error if you do that?

Comment: No problem, if I had a pound/dollar for every time I made a mistake like that...........