# Access Overflow Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

Doing statistical work with the Lahman database and MS-Access 2013.  I have several views created to calculate linear weights of batting events as an intermediate step in calculating advanced statistics such as wOBA, wRC, etc. These views take the entire universe of baseball statistics and group them by year.  The last of these views (RunValues2) has a calculated field that returns values with no issue.  That field is `runMinus` as shown in the abbreviated query below (Pls ignore the unnecessary join unless it's the reason this one works):

```
SELECT RunValues.yearID
, RunValues.RperOut
, RunValues.runBB
, RunValues.runHB
, RunValues.run1B
, RunValues.run2B
, RunValues.run3B
, RunValues.runHR
, RunValues.runSB
, RunValues.runCS
, Sum([runBB]*([BB]-nz([ibb]))+[runHB]*nz([HBP])+[run1B]*([H]-[2b]-[3b]-[HR])+[run2B]
*[2b]+[run3B]*[3b]+1.4*[HR]+[runSB]*nz([SB])-[runCS]*nz([CS]))/Sum([ab]-[h]+nz([SF]))
AS runMinus
FROM RunValues INNER JOIN (Batting INNER JOIN v_PrimaryPos ON Batting.playerID = v_PrimaryPos.playerID) ON RunValues.yearID = Batting.yearID
GROUP BY RunValues.yearID, RunValues.RperOut, RunValues.runBB, RunValues.runHB, RunValues.run1B, RunValues.run2B, RunValues.run3B, RunValues.runHR, RunValues.runSB, RunValues.runCS
ORDER BY RunValues.yearID DESC;
```

I am re-creating these views with the totals grouped by league.  Otherwise, the views are the same, just referencing different views with the same field names.

```
SELECT rvl.yearID
, rvl.lgID
, rvl.RperOut
, rvl.runBB
, rvl.runHB
, rvl.run1B
, rvl.run2B
, rvl.run3B
, rvl.runHR
, rvl.runSB
, rvl.runCS
, Sum([runBB]*([BB]-nz([ibb]))+[runHB]*nz([HBP])+[run1B]*([H]-[2b]-[3b]-[HR])+[run2B]
*[2b]+[run3B]*[3b]+1.4*[HR]+[runSB]*nz([SB])-[runCS]*nz([CS]))
/IIF(Sum([ab]-[h]+nz([SF]))=0,1,Sum([ab]-[h]+nz([SF]))) AS runMinus

FROM RunValuesLeague rvl INNER JOIN BattingLg ON rvl.yearID = BattingLg.yearID AND rvl.lgID=BattingLg.lgID
GROUP BY rvl.yearID, rvl.lgID, rvl.RperOut, rvl.runBB, rvl.runHB, rvl.run1B, rvl.run2B, rvl.run3B, rvl.runHR, rvl.runSB, rvl.runCS
ORDER BY rvl.yearID DESC;
```

When creating the new views, I get an Overload error with no number.  Having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048038/ms-access-overflow-not-resolved) answer, you'll see I added an `IIF` function to make sure I was not dividing by zero.  That did not resolve the issue.

Apologies for the length of this question, but I am stumped and wanted to give as much info as possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Your IIf() returns 0 if the expression calc is 0. Return 1 instead.

Comment: Good catch!  Unfortunately, this did not solve it. I changed it to 1 but the Overflow error persists.  Editing the snippet above to reflect that change.

Comment: Dividing by 0 in expression returns #Div/0! in my test. So something else may be going on to trigger overflow error.

Comment: No joy there either.  Changed the nz(field) to nz(field,0) and the Overflow error persists.

Comment: You were too fast, edited my comment to remove that suggestion. At this point, would have to provide data for analysis. Break up the calc into 2 fields to see what each Sum is producing.

Comment: @June7 - On the left side of the calc, it's the SUM() that is triggering the overflow error.  I can remove it, but concerned that will affect the result and not sure why SUM() works on the first view.

Comment: Create a copy of your query.  Remove the grouping.  Remove the Sum() but leave the calculation.  Run query.  Inspect total number of rows. Inspect individual values for "anomalies".   Look for excessively large values, etc.  If needed, copy to a spreadsheet and try to sum up values there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By second thought, I believe you can reduce it to:

```
SELECT rvl.yearID
, rvl.lgID
, rvl.RperOut
, rvl.runBB
, rvl.runHB
, rvl.run1B
, rvl.run2B
, rvl.run3B
, rvl.runHR
, rvl.runSB
, rvl.runCS
, ([runBB]*([BB]-Nz([ibb],0))+[runHB]*Nz([HBP],0)+[run1B]*([H]-[2b]-[3b]-[HR])+[run2B]
*[2b]+[run3B]*[3b]+1.4*[HR]+[runSB]*Nz([SB],0)-[runCS]*Nz([CS],0))
/IIF(([ab]-[h]+Nz([SF],0))=0,1,([ab]-[h]+Nz([SF],0))) AS runMinus

FROM RunValuesLeague rvl 
INNER JOIN BattingLg 
ON rvl.yearID=BattingLg.yearID AND rvl.lgID=BattingLg.lgID

ORDER BY rvl.yearID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Overflow typically means overflow of an Integer.

So, as already noted, first force a numeric value from Nz, then convert all values to currency (if four decimals or less) or double:

```
Sum(CCur([runBB])*(CCur([BB])-CCur(Nz([ibb],0)))+ ...
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample? The only way I get an overflow is sum of an undefined expression `Sum(0/0)`.

Comment: No, I'm not into baseball. I have no idea what these figures could be.

Comment: I just thought about a simple query (not related to baseball) that overflows. I tried summing max long values in a table, but they get converted and displayed. Division by zero has its own error msg, null values too. The only query that overflows is `SELECT Sum(0/0) FROM myTable;`

Comment: Oh. I can't recall the exact conditions, only that it helped to be more specific and force data types.

Comment: Too bad, would have been interesting.